# Is there a way to force open a link in a default mobile browser instead of the in-app browser?

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink, mobile-browser

We want to send links to people over chat and it's important it opens in the default safari or chrome mobile instead of apps in-app browsers. For example, if you send a link in Linkedin, it opens in their half-baked in-app browser. Can you automatically force it go to the browser?

Have tried putting target attributes of blank or system and that doesn't work.